# Find all instances where count is less than

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a big log file which contains IDs. If the ID is present in the log more than 5 times - it's a success. If it's less - I want to know which ID it is.

Ultimately I need a way in Notepad++ that would give me a list of all IDs (`[0-9]{10}`) where the instance of that is 5 or less.

Is this somehow possible?

Edit: The format of the file is a standard log4j log, so it has a ton of other data. Example (ID in this case is 12345678901234567)

```
[08-08-2015 02:08:00] [INFO ] Service [329]: Attempting to substitute message ID with 12345678901234567
[08-08-2015 02:08:00] [DEBUG] ParsedBlock [49]: 3296825 => 12345678901234567
[08-08-2015 02:08:00] [DEBUG] LifeCycle [149]: All messages have not yet been sent. Waiting another 2000 milliseconds. [Send: false]
[08-08-2015 02:08:00] [DEBUG] LifeCycle$5 [326]: Running 5, 2592
```

Comment: Is the file *just* those IDs, or is there other data? Can you show a sample part of the file?

Comment: No, this is not possible with a simple regex, not in N++

Comment: sound like a job for `sed | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -v "^[1234] "` or some such

Comment: What defines an ID? Is it 10+ digits? You suggested `[0-9]{10}`, which would match **exactly** 10 digits, but your example is `12345678901234567`.

Comment: @BrianStephens IDs are 17 digit numbers within the file. Is there a way I can just extract all 17 digit numbers from the log? Then I could possibly use your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in Notepad++ in the first place, you can take advantage of its functionality outside of Search. Be sure you do all this in a **copy** of the file, not the original, since it makes changes to the file. Since you haven't answered about the format of the file, I'm assuming the file is just the IDs, one on each line.

The first step is to sort the IDs so all the duplicates appear contiguously: `Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort Lines As Integers Ascending`

Then do this Search/Replace (with Search Mode set to regex):

- Search: `(\d{17}\r\n)\1{5,}|(\d{17}\r\n)\2*`
- Replace: `$2`

You'll be left with only the IDs that occur 5 or fewer times.

**Explanation:**
The first half of the alternation `(\d{17}\r\n)\1{5,}` matches any IDs that repeat 6 or more times. The second half `(\d{17}\r\n)\2*` matches any other IDs, capturing the first instance in group #2. Then the replace puts back that group with `$2`.

Comment: Sadly it's not just IDs. I've added the sample of the file to my original question.

Comment: @MetalWing: OK, since the IDs are mixed with lots of other data, do this step first to extract them. Search for `.*(\d{17}).*\r\n|.*\r\n`, replace with `$1\r\n`.